# Multistage dockerfile COPY from image - file not found

Tags: dockerfile

I am trying to COPY JAVA binaries from an already existing image over to new image using multistage dockerfile.

After the image is built, I do see all the files in the new image but when I execute JAVA, it gives me no such file or directory.

```
FROM quay.io/<private-repo>/node:12.8.0-slim
COPY --from=quay.io/<private-repo>/openjdk:8u212-jre-alpine /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
# Setup JAVA_HOME, this is useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
RUN export JAVA_HOME
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

`RUN export JAVA_HOME` - will export the environment file only for the specific run instance. If you are logging in using `docker exec` and verifying the JAVA_HOME value. It will not exists.

Similarly `ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` - will be used only on the run instance.

If you want to have these variables across multiple sessions append these entries to `/etc/profile`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I actually logging into the container during run time so I do see the variables set correctly. But upon execution of java it gives "no such file or directory".

Strangely, even if I go inside that JAVA_HOME/bin folder I still cannot execute it. I do see all the files there though.